# How to calculate distinct value from a list of key value pairs in column delimited by pipe in PostgreSQL

Tags: string, postgresql

I have a varchar column which contains value and I want to extract the value against key finance and ignore words like testing,abc.

```
Other:transaction1|finance:insurance|finance:insurance|Other:Place|finance:testing|finance:abc
```

Output: insurance

Comment: You say you want `ignore words like testing,abc`. What if `finance` key except `insurance` word also have value `bla`, then what is desired result? Do you want both words (`insurance` and `bla`) in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with temp as (
    select unnest(string_to_array(t.str,'|')) as str
    from (values('Other:transaction1|finance:insurance|finance:insurance|Other:Place|finance:testing|finance:abc')) as t(str)
)
select distinct substring(str from position(':' in str)+1 for length(str))
from temp 
where   str ~'finance:' and --matching finance
        str !~'testing' and -- ignore words testing
        str !~'abc'     -- ignore words abc
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `regexp_matches`, something like this:

```
with the_table(id, col) as(
    select 1, 'Other:transaction1|finance:testing|finance:testing|finance:Place|finance:testing|finance:insurance'::text union all
    select 2, 'finance:insurance'::text union all
    select 3, 'ffinance:insurance|finance:testing'::text  union all
    select 4, 'Other:transaction1|finance:insurance|finance:insurance|Other:Place|finance:testing|finance:abc'::text
)

select distinct id, arr[1] as word from (
    select id, regexp_matches('|'||col, '\|finance:([^\|]+)', 'g') as arr 
    from the_table
) t
where 
arr[1] not in('testing', 'abc') -- there is words you don't want to see in result
order by id
```

This gives every words except "black list" as different rows. I use unique column `id` just for showing, which words corresponding which row.